# Angular Js $compile Javascript Window Scoping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I'm having a problem with the scoping of `this` inside of an angular-ui bootstrap modal. When I run the following code outside of a modal I have no problems with it:

```js
  var GlobalVariable = GlobalVariable || {};

    (function(){

      doSomethingWith(GlobalVariable.field);

    })();
```

When called outside of the $modal GlobalVariable.field is perfectly accessible. As soon as I run this code inside a $modal, GlobalVariable.field is undefined. Now I can fix this problem by directly accessing window.GlobalVariable.field inside the $modal dialog but the problem is that the `doSomethingWith` method in this case is a 3rd party library which needs access to the global variables. I'm not about to go through all the third party libraries and add "window." on to all of the globally scoped variables.

I know that when I call $modal.open passing in some HTML that it gets mangled through the angular $compile function (which I presume `eval()`s the HTML as part of the process). My guess is that when $compile processes it, it assigns it a fresh this object meaning we don't inherit all of the globally scoped variables from window.

Is there any way that I can get angular's $compile to force 'inheritance' of the window's global variables all the way down to my modal?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Plunker that I generated from the Angular-UI bootstrap documentation:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jMcvTBDcrkPU7p4gFejT?p=preview

```
resolve
```

As you can see, the modal creates a new scope, so anything you want to use inside that scope must be passed in using "resolve" and returned.  There's no need to force inheritance when you can just pass whatever you need in.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question. This is about gaining access to all Javascript global variables associated with `window`. It's not specific to angular, it just happens to be angular which is `$compile`-ing the HTML/Javascript.

Comment: Is the variable declared in the HTML that's being injected into the modal?

Comment: The variable is declared in the page outside the modal. It's a website-wide object declared independently of angular. An important point is that I need my code inside the modal to remain indifferent to whether it's displayed inside a $modal or not (that's why I can't assign the variable to a `$scope.new()` or use the $modal `resolve` functionality).

Comment: Interesting, I'd have to see a more specific code sample.  I updated the Plunker in line with what you said (added a var called someGlobal, added a button that calls a function I added within the modal controller which does a window.alert on the values of someGlobal).  Have another look at http://plnkr.co/edit/jMcvTBDcrkPU7p4gFejT?p=preview - does this match what you're doing?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hpQJnKcm8PcSpHt5eY0j - This plunkr has it set up in essentially the same way that I have it set up. Unfortunately, the Javascript I've stuck inside the modal doesn't get executed at all. Not quite sure what's going on there but it gives you a flavour of what we're trying to do.

Comment: I think I see where you're coming from.  The HTML/JS you have for the modal -  is that generated by the third party component, or do you generate it?